# SAS: Rolling window regressions for daily values

Tags: sas, regression, sliding-window

I need rolling regression outputs on a daily basis. The dataset are stock returns and volume and the model is only return=volume.
I need the regression coefficient for the past 30 days, each day one day further such that the 30-day window stays intact.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is just restrict the data by date: `data model; set begin(where=(date_var >= date()-30)); run; ` Then run this data through the model.

Comment: Thank you. Problem is that I have around 300mn observations spanning 5 years of data...

Comment: So what you want is to do is to run the model retrospectively?

Comment: Exactly, backwards 30 days, day by day

Comment: Communities.sas.com has some very good code that does this using a data step to process it and using temporary arrays. Since you're using only a 30 day window this is relatively easy and quick approach. You have a single pass of the data and it can scale to other lengths/formulas. I think the answer is via mkeintz on the forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question I understood that you want to run model for every month for a huge data set retrospectively. Here is something similar that I've done recently.

```
/*Select the parts of the data from base data based on input.*/
%macro model_by_dates(id, date1, date2);
    data to_model;
        set begin(where=( &date1. < date_var < &date2.));
    run;

   /*YOUR model code here*/

    data result_file; 
        set From_model; 
        id=&id; /*To recognize from which model this is from.*/
    run;

    /*If you have huge files, do permanent data after every 10 loops or so. Depends.*/
    proc append base=all_Results data=result_file force; run;
%mend model_by_dates;

/*here we create the dates list. You can do this in multiple ways. Datdiff maybe?*/

%let maxmonths=3;

data dates;
    do i=0 to &maxmonths. by 1;
        begin=date()-(i*30);
        end = date()-( (i+1)*30);
        output;
    end;
run;


/*This is the master switch. It executes the macro for each row of the dates.*/
data _NULL_;
    set dates;
    call execute('%nrstr(%model_by_dates('
            ||strip(id)||','
            ||strip(begin)||','
            ||strip(end)||
    '))');
run;
```

**EDIT** Based on further clarification I'm changing the date list creation:

```
data dates;
    do i=0 to 30 by 1;
        begin=date()-(i+30);
        end = date()- i ;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Fantastic framework! I will try it with the regressions asap

Comment: @MaBo88 This appoach gets very time consuming very fast. Run with few lines of code first. (Well, depends of course. )

Comment: @MaBo88 did it work?

Comment: Yes it did! Sorry I forgot to mark it successfu! Thanks @pinegulf